# Why were these edits rejected?

Tags: discussion, edits

I recently asked a fairly theoretical question on SO that got many answers, several of which were wrong.

One user had a good answer, which required a few clarifications to be an excellent answer.

After accepting the good answer, I edited it to make it more precise. I added 5 relevant references from the literature that would be extremely helpful to anyone researching the same problem. I added notes explaining why the other answers, while closely related to the problem, were inadequate.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10658865

My edit was rejected by a vote count of 3:2 on the basis that "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

There is no passage in the edit adressing the author of the post. Perhaps the edit reviewers got confused by the colloquial use of "you" as in, "when you do this, you get ..."?

If there's another reason why my edit isn't appropriate, I'd like to know so I can improve the answer. As it stands, I believe the edit 1) refines the existing answer, 2) adds useful references and 3) clarifies subtle differences with other related problems that tripped up other people who attempted to answer the question (I believe these are therefore relevant as part of the answer, not just as comments.)

Comment: Holy crap that's a rewrite, not an edit :| you should post it as another answer in supplement to the edited answer.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will do that (putting on my airing of grievances hat). Do you want to post as an answer?

Comment: Nah, I'm just going to rewrite @Makoto's answer to include the suggestion as well as details and links as to why this would be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

Two things jump out at me:

- there are *huge swathes* of text that are changed, which is likely what led to the visceral reaction to reject your changes, and
- it *appears* to, at first glance, greatly change what the answer is.

Those who have the time to actually peruse the edit would have seen that a few other bits were added in, but overall it doesn't *really* take away from the answer.  I think the main concern was that people might have had the impression that you were supplying commentary as opposed to enhancing the answer.

Comment: What would be the appropriate course of action? Re-submit the edits?

Comment: Tough to say.  I don't have the time personally to peruse the edit right now to see if any meaning was truly lost, or I'd go forward with the changes myself.  Let others discuss this here on Meta to see if what I'm thinking makes sense.